# jQuery function not acting like I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
//The user clicked on a species to delete it. We need to use event delegation because items are added dynamically.
$('#speciesAdded').on('click', 'li', function (event) {

    // Let's make sure this is what the user wants to do?
    alertify.confirm("Do you wish to delete the sighting?", function (e) {
        if (e) {
            // User clicked Ok - No need to do anything

        } else {
            // User clicked cancel
            return;
        }
    });

    alert("Howdy!");

    ...
    ...
});
```

When this fires the JavaScript alert dialog appears **at the same time** as the alertify confirmation dialog. In other words, the code occurring after the alertify executes before the user even has a chance to confirm the action. I'm not sure what's going on here How can I prevent this?

Comment: You need to put that alert in the callback of the alertify.

Comment: @igormilla is right...

Comment: What does `alert("Howdy!");` have to do with deleting a species? It doesn't make much sense. It doesn't sound as if the OP _wants_ the alert in the callback...?

Comment: @Andy i think it should happen in that code that shown as `...` and therefore it also should be moved into the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to put your alert method call inside the confirm callback...

```
$('#speciesAdded').on('click', 'li', function (event) {

    // Let's make sure this is what the user wants to do?
    alertify.confirm("Do you wish to delete the sighting?", function (e) {
        if (e) {
            // User clicked Ok - No need to do anything
            // Do something on okay
            alert("Howdy!");
            ...
             ...
        } else {
            // User clicked cancel
            // 
            return;
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: as well as all the code he put as `...`, I think he want that also to be executed only if user clicked `ok`.